# Copy value from previous matching row into new matching row

Tags: r, for-loop

My example data frame is constructed as follows:

```
ID       <- c("1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2")
Current  <- c(1.12, NA, 3.66, 8.95, 4.73, 7.82)
Previous <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
df       <- data.frame(ID, Current, Previous, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
```

Adding an extra `ID` to `levels(df$ID)` by writing `levels(df$ID) <- c(levels(df$ID), "3")` results in:

```
> levels(df$ID)
[1] "1" "2" "3"
```

(I am adding an extra level because the data frame I am currently working with contains a lot of levels that do not even occur once.)

Writing `df` now prints:

```
  ID Current Previous
1  1    1.12       NA
2  2      NA       NA
3  1    3.66       NA
4  2    8.95       NA
5  1    4.73       NA
6  2    7.82       NA
```

Because `typeof(df$Current)` is `"double"` and `typeof(df$Previous)` is `"logical"`, I would like to convert the `Previous` column to `"double"`. In order to achieve this, I write:

```
df$Previous <- as.numeric(as.character(df$Previous))
```

Writing `typeof(df$Previous)` now results in `"double"`.

I would now like to do the following: Take the first `ID 1` entry of `Current` and copy it to the second `ID 1` entry of `Previous` and so on **if** the `Current` value is not an `NA`. That is, the resulting table should look like this:

```
  ID Current Previous
1  1    1.12       NA
2  2      NA       NA
3  1    3.66     1.12
4  2    8.95       NA
5  1    4.73     3.66
6  2    7.82     8.95
```

I already tried doing this by writing the following `for` loop, but it did not work and I do not know what I did wrong:

```
i = 1
for(i in length(unique(df$ID))) {
  j = 1
  k = 1
  idLocationAbsolute = 1
  for(j in length(df$ID)) {
    if(unique(df$ID)[i] == df$ID[j]) {
      idLocationAbsolute[k] = j
      k = k + 1
    }
  }
  if(k > 1) {
    k = k - 1
    l = 1
    for(l in k) {
      if(!is.na(idLocationAbsolute[l])) {
        df$Previous[l + 1] = df$Current[l]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please note that I wrote `idLocationAbsolute = 1` because R prints an error message otherwise. But I cannot tell whether this is a good thing to do or if it just breaks the whole code. I, however, suppose that this is not the cause of the code not doing what it should do.

Comment: You need `lag` by group, With `dplyr`, you can do `df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Previous = lag(Current))`